# Plotting points based on what value they end up being in matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I apologize, since I don't exactly know how to word my title. I'm brand new to Python and especially new to matplotlib. I am also using numpy for my arrays in this case.

Currently, I have a set of data: `X` that has four properties. Each property is a column, and each row is a set of data points (lets just say they are represented by numbers for now). Here is a small example:

```
X
(height)  (weight)  (gender)  (hair color)
6           32.1        0           12
1.112       6.12        1           9
4            2          0           6    
2            3.2        0           11
```

I also have an array `Y` that corresponds to an integer value from 0 - 2. It is just an `np.array` but each element corresponds to that row of values in `X`. So for example if `Y = array([0,2,1,1])` then I have these pairs:

```
Y          X
0 -> (6, 32.1, 0, 12)
2 -> (1.112, 6.12, 1, 9)
1 -> (4, 2, 0, 6)
1 -> (2, 3.2, 0, 11)
```

What I want to do is create **separate** scatter plots for each pair of these properties:

```
(height, weight) -> (0,1)
(height, gender) -> (0,2)
(height, hair color) -> (0, 3)
```

And I want each data point to have a color that corresponds with the `Y` value. So `y = 0 = 'b'`, `y = 1 = 'g'`, and `y = 2 = 'r'`

I know how to create a scatter plot (in this case, just the height and weight column) that will map the pairs that I want using

```
plt.plot(X[:,0], X[:,1], 'o', c='b')
plt.show()
```

However I don't know how I can then relate each of these points to the `Y` value that holds its color, since I can only input one color. I would appreciate any help, or tutorials that could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map Y to rgb colors and use "scatter" to plot points with different colors:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = numpy.array([[6, 32.1, 0, 12],
    [1.112, 6.12, 1, 9],
    [4, 2, 0, 6],
    [2, 3.2, 0, 11]])

Y = numpy.array([0, 1, 1, 2])

# map numbers to rgb colors
Y_color = numpy.zeros(shape=(Y.size, 3))
Y_color[Y == 0] = (1,0,0)
Y_color[Y == 1] = (0,1,0)
Y_color[Y == 2] = (0,0,1)

# use scatter instead of plot
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=Y_color)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked! As a side note, what does `numpy.zeros(shape=(Y.size,3))` do? Does it just create an array with Y.size amount of rows? And how does the `shape=` work? Looking at the documentation, it just says that `shape` returns `(# rows, # columns)`

Comment: zeros returns a array filled with "0". The shape of an array defines the dimension and size per dimension. Thus numpy.zeros(shape=(Y.size,3)) returns a 2d-array with Y.size elements in the first (outer) dimension and 3 elements for the second dimension (in your case the colors initialized with (0,0,0)